# How to use setters and getters in different java file

Tags: java, android

This is my setters and getters in ShoppingListName.java

```
public class ShoppingListName {
    private String shoppingListName;

    public String getShoppingListName() {
        return shoppingListName;
    }

    public void setShoppingListName(String shoppingListName) {
        this.shoppingListName = shoppingListName;
    }
}
```

I did this in MainMenu.java

```
ShoppingListName shoppingList = new ShoppingListName();
shoppingList.setShoppingListName(inputListName.getText().toString());
```

And I'm trying to pass the string to a different java file (CreateList.java)
How can I do that?

I tried this.

```
ShoppingListName shoppingList = new ShoppingListName();
Log.e("ShoppingListName", "" + shoppingList.getShoppingListName());
```

But obvious I'm receiving a null return.

Comment: I suggest you to use `Dependence Injection`, as it is good for a better program structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****Getter Setter Class***

```
public class ShoppingListName {
private static String shoppingListName;
public static String getShoppingListName() {
    return shoppingListName;
}
public static void setShoppingListName(String shoppingListName) {
    ShoppingListName.shoppingListName = shoppingListName;
}
```

}

***To set the value**
    ShoppingListName.setShoppingListName("the value that u need to set");*

***To get the value**
    String value=ShoppingListName.getShoppingListName();**

**UPDATE**

as @laalto mentioned in the comment. separate pojo class with static parameter to store data for some extend is not the perfect solution.

instead of that according to me, If you want to save the data for a long time save it in shared preferences otherwise create a non static variable in application class and use like this

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
        private int globalVariable=1;

        public int getGlobalVariable() {
                return globalVariable;
        }

        public void setGlobalVariable(int globalVariable) {
                this.globalVariable = globalVariable;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
                //reinitialize variable
        }
}
```

And in your Activity, do this,

```
(HelloApplication)getApplication()).setGlobalVariable(10);
int valiable=((HelloApplication)getApplication()).getGlobalVariable();
```

Comment: Y it has been down voted? You should give reason to down vote an answer.

Comment: Using a `static` var is a terrible way to solve the problem, and it only works properly if there's only one `ShoppingList` instance. That could be the reason why someone downvoted.

Comment: I wont use like this often but for his case i thought it would be good.,can u elaborate your statement and can u suggest or post better solution for this.? @laalto

Answer (score 1):

> And I'm trying to pass the string to a different java file
>   (CreateList.java) How can I do that?

Presumably, what you mean here is that you'd like to pass the `String` to a method defined in the class `CreateList`.

So just create a method on `CreateList` that takes a `String`, and does whatever it needs to do.

```
public class CreateList {

    public static void doSomething(String listName) { 
       //do whatever you want with it
    }
}
```

As a side note, your class ShoppingListName doesn't seem to model any kind of meaningful real world object.  Consider changing it to :

```
public class ShoppingList {

    List<ShoppingItems> items;
    String listName;
 ..   
 ..
}
```

The same goes for`CreateList`.  What is the primary responsibility for this object?

Answer (score 1):

`ShoppingListName` class instance in `MainMenu.java` is different from the instance in `CreateList.java`. Obviously the new instance in `CreateList.java` cannot get the value you have set in the instance in `MainMenu.java`. You have to somehow pass the instance from `MainMenu.java` to `CreateList.java` or share the same instance between the two classes.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* make getter and setter methods **static** and then that last call you used would work. Then, *provided* the flow is such that get method is called *after* set method, you would'nt have to *explicitly* pass anything.

Thus, *effectively*, you would be *sharing* the single instance across as many other classes as you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
public class ShoppingListName extend Application{
    private String shoppingListName;

    public String getShoppingListName() {
        return shoppingListName;
    }

    public void setShoppingListName(String shoppingListName) {
        this.shoppingListName = shoppingListName;
    }
}
```

in Android Manifest.xml :

```
<application
    android:name="yourPacket.ShoppingListName"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="yourPacket.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

in MainMenu.java :

```
ShoppingListName shoppinglistname = (ShoppingListName) MainMenu.this.getApplicationContext();
// Now you can get and set shoppinglistname object
```